# adding columns with formulas to a google forms results sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheets document (workbook) that contains a sheet that collects the responses from a google form.

One of the columns (lets say column A) is some number (like a unique id for something).
I also have another sheet in the same workbook that has a table that maps the id from column A to a description - lets say Sheed2!A is the list of sorted ids and Sheet2!B is the descriptions.

I want to add another column (B) to the Responses sheet and have it display the description.
No problem with inserting the additional B column.

now the issue is how to populate Responses!B so that it would display the descriptions...

Here is what I tried so far:

First I tried setting Responses!B2 to

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",xlookup(A2:A,IDs,Descriptions,"",0,2))  where IDs is Sheet2!A2:A and Descriptions is Sheet2!B2:B
```

This worked but had a problem when I tried filtering the Responses sheet using filters that hid the second row where I entered the formula. when Row 2 was filtered, no other row would display the value. OK than I said to myself - not sure why it does that - but lets move the formua to Responses!B1 and change it to return the header as well... i.e.

```
={"Desc";ARRAYFORMULA(if(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",xlookup(A2:A,IDs,Descriptions,"",0,2))}
```

that took care of this issue but I have additional sheets that use =filter to import data form the Responses sheet and now this new B column with the description would break in those importing sheets when ever I tried to filter the Responses sheet.

Then I decided to populate
the actual cells on the B column of the Responses sheet with

```
=if(ISBLANK(Brow),"",xlookup(Brow,IDs,Descriptions,"",0,2))
```

where Brow is B followed with a running number (to get the id for each row...).
The issue with this is obviously that when a new form is filled the formula does not automatically populate the newly created Row with the newly submitted form data.

any Idea for a better solution?

will I have to resort to using code to detect when a new row is added and inject this formula?

Comment: Share a sample data or dummy copy of your spreadsheet so we can replicate what you have. Remove sensitive if any.

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier just to create your own sheet similar to the linked sheet with all the extra stuff that you want using onFormSubmit trigger.

Comment: thanks @Cooper - I will have a look at onFormSubmit

Answer (score 1):

Logan is right, it would be much easier to see your setup. Cooper also has a point, sticking your own info in using the onFormSubmit trigger would probably be cleaner...

But this is a variation to the Arrayformula attempt. It would go in Row 1, assuming column A is the Form's default "Timestamp" column. This looks at Row 1 and sets the title of it's column as "Descriptions". If, it's not row 1, then is should do your lookup...? Best of luck!

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len($A:$A),If($A:$A <> "Timestamp",if(A:A<>"",xlookup(A:A,IDs,Descriptions,"",0,2), "Descriptions"),))
```